# use of layout_weight without being stretched

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

I got 7 buttons aligned horizontally in a layout by giving them each a weight of 1. This however stretches the button so the take up the same amount of space on the screen. I need the buttons to remain the good aspect ratio and still take up the whole width by making use of whitespace between the buttons. Is this possible with weight?

Comment: Just place empty `View` widgets between them and give those a `layout_weight` of `1`.

Comment: well thats no good...
The reason i want this is because most screens will fill up nicely however bigger screen (or higher pixel density) creates streched buttons

Comment: Hard to understand. Provide a layout and maybe a screenshot of what you see and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stretch not buttons but space around them, put buttons to containers and set weight to them. Also take a look at TableLayout and GridLayout.